# Sort a PHP Array by Certain Keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am still very confused on how to sort a array by certain values. I know you are supposed to use the `CMD` function and the `usort()`. Yet I am just confused on what I am suppose to do. I would like to sort my array so the keys "Bronze, "Silver", "Gold", "Platinum" are shown in that order. I am not sure how I would put what I need into the following:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
   return strcmp(???);
}
```

So basically I have a array this is listen like this:

```
"itemname" => "Value"
```

I would like the whole thing to be ordered by the value of the "Value". Value could be "Bronze"/"Silver"/"gold"/"Platinum". And I would like it to be sorted in that order.

**EDIT 2**

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM postallions WHERE userid = :userid";
$params = array(':userid' => $userid);
try{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$columns = $stmt->fetch();

$postallionlist = $columns;

print_r($postallionlist);

function compareMedals( $a, $b ) {
    $aMap = array(0 => 'None', 1 => 'Bronze', 2 => 'Silver', 3 => 'Gold', 4 => 'Platinum', 5 => 'Uncomplete', 6 => 'Complete');
    $aValues = array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    $a = str_ireplace($aMap, $aValues, $a);
    $b = str_ireplace($aMap, $aValues, $b);
    return $a - $b;
}
usort($postallionlist, 'compareMedals');
print_r($postallionlist);
```

**EDIT 3**
The print_r and then the var_dump:

```
Array ( [userid] => 1 [0] => 1 [p1] => Silver [1] => Silver [p2] => Platinum [2] => Platinum [p3] => None [3] => None [p4] => None [4] => None [p5] => Bronze [5] => Bronze [p6] => Gold [6] => Gold [p7] => Complete [7] => Complete [p8] => None [8] => None [p9] => None [9] => None [p10] => None [10] => None )
array (size=22)
  'userid' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'p1' => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  'p2' => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  'p3' => string 'None' (length=4)
  3 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p4' => string 'None' (length=4)
  4 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p5' => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  'p6' => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  6 => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  'p7' => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  7 => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  'p8' => string 'None' (length=4)
  8 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p9' => string 'None' (length=4)
  9 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p10' => string 'None' (length=4)
  10 => string 'None' (length=4)
```

Comment: more details please ... could you give us your array and how you want it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert names to positions you like.

Here's a working prototype:

```
$aMedals = array(  
    'adbv'         => 'Gold', 
    'sdgg'         => 'Bronze', 
    'dsgggsd'      =>'Platinum', 
    'dsggsg'       => 'Silver',
    '34g434h34'    => 'Bronze', 
    'g34h4h'       =>'Platinum', 
    'g34h4h'       =>'Gold', 
    'dsg34t43tgsg' => 'Silver'
    );
var_dump( $aMedals );
function compareMedals( $a, $b )
{
    $aMap    = array( 0 => 'Bronze', 1 => 'Silver', 2 => 'Gold', 3 => 'Platinum');
    $aValues = array( 0, 1, 2, 3 );
    $a       = str_ireplace( $aMap, $aValues, $a );
    $b       = str_ireplace( $aMap, $aValues, $b );
    return $a - $b;
}    
usort( $aMedals, 'compareMedals');
var_dump( $aMedals );
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Bronze"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Bronze"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Silver"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Silver"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "Gold"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "Gold"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "Platinum"
}
```

Comment: Whenever I use your code it doubles my array for some reason. IDK why :( lol

Comment: I think that's just the output from two print_r statements. Comment the first one out. If it isn't, your database may be retrieving too many rows and you may have an issue with your sql.

Comment: Hi, I printed before and after. Right before I executed the function it prints the right amount of rows. Right after I run the function it adds a extra 11 rows. It is odd lol

Comment: post the before array structure and I'll take a look.

Comment: Sorry, new to arrays. How do I exactly post the array structure? var_dump()?

Comment: Ok posted the print_r and the var_dump

Comment: I checked... the amount of elements going in match the amount going out. If you want to add additional mappings you'll need to update the map array and include the fields in the positions you want them in.